# Variable overwritten inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following piece of code in Python 2.7

```
abc=[[1,2,3],[0,1,2]]
def make_change(some_list):
    for i in range(len(some_list)):
        if some_list[i][0]==0:
            some_list[i]=[]
    return some_list

new_list=make_change(abc)

print abc
print new_list
```

My understanding was that it should produce the following output.

`[[1,2,3],[0,1,2]]`

```
[[1,2,3],[]]
```

But the python actually produces

```
[[1,2,3],[]] 

[[1,2,3],[]]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You do not copy the list when calling, you copy the *reference* to the list. So `some_list` and `abc` refer to the *same* list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent this issue by copying the list while passing it to the function:

```
abc=[[1,2,3],[0,1,2]]
def make_change(some_list):
    for i in range(len(some_list)):
        if some_list[i][0]==0:
            some_list[i]=[]
    return some_list

new_list=make_change(abc[:])

print abc
print new_list
```

The changed part:

```
new_list=make_change(abc[:])
```

The reason this happens is Python passes the list by reference, so changes will be made to the original as well. Using [:] creates a shallow copy, which is enough to prevent this.

Comment: This produces a shallow copy, which is still incorrect.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The modification(s) only applies to the outer container, so it is *correct*, in some sense, although not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the list you pass to a function unless you specifically want the function to change a list that's passed to it.  Make a copy of the list (or any other mutable object) and work on the copy. If you're using compound objects (objects with objects in them) use copy.deepcopy to make sure everything is a copy.

Since functions exist to encapsulate the weird stuff you have to do, doing weird stuff to the objects you're passing to a function rarely makes sense to me.  The other answer has you pass a slice copy of the list to the function. Why not make the whole thing more readable by passing your mutable to the function and having the function create the copy.  Better encapsulation = less annoying code.

```
abc=[[1,2,3],[0,1,2]]
def make_change(some_list):
    from copy import deepcopy
    new_list = deepcopy(some_list)
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
        if new_list[i][0]==0:
            new_list[i]=[]
    return new_list

new_list=make_change(abc)

print abc
print new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehensions to the rescue!

```
abc=[[1,2,3],[0,1,2]]

def make_change(some_list):
    return [[] if a[0]==0 else a for a in some_list]

make_change(abc)
[[1, 2, 3], []]
```